# Не приходит callback_query от telegram bot PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Уже что только не перепробовал - но никак не могу решить. Использую эту бибилиотеку - https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api . Так все работает, на команды отвечает и даже если нажать на кнопку та которая с ссылкой то все открывается - но вот callback_query почему-то уловить не могу. Вот код:

```
PackageLoader::Get()->loadPackage('Telegram');

$token = Development_Service::Get()->getTelegramKey();
$bot = new \TelegramBot\Api\Client($token);

$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$chat_id = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];

if (isset($update['callback_query'])) {
    $bot->sendMessage($chat_id, "Daaa!");
}

$bot->command('start', function ($message) use ($bot) {
    $answer = "Добро пожаловать!\nВведите свой пин-код c помощью команды /pincode\n\nПример: /pincode 1234";

    $keyboard = new \TelegramBot\Api\Types\Inline\InlineKeyboardMarkup(
        [
            [
                ['text' => 'link', 'url' => 'https://core.telegram.org'],
                ['text' => 'Test', 'callback_data' => 'test123']
            ]
        ]
    );

    $bot->sendMessage($message->getChat()->getId(), $answer, null, false, null, $keyboard);
});
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку которая должна высылать данные - просто возле неё появляются часики и все..
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Все таки решил. Запрос на самом деле приходит, но id чата находится в другом месте, по этому он и не отправлял - вот:

```
if(isset($update['callback_query'])){//Если была нажата кнопка
    $chatId = $update['callback_query']['message']['chat']['id'];
    $data = $update['callback_query']['data'];
    $bot->sendMessage($chatId, "Daaa!");
}
```

Надеюсь кому-то помог. Так же чтобы проверить какие вебхуки вам приходят можете воспользоваться сайтом https://webhook.site - он лично помог мне

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку `westacks/telebot`:

```php
// index.php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use WeStacks\TeleBot\Objects\Update;
use WeStacks\TeleBot\TeleBot;

$bot = new TeleBot('123456:ABC-DEF1234ghIkl-zyx57W2v1u123ew11');

// Start command
$bot->addHandler(function (Update $update) use ($bot) {
    if (!$message = $update->message()) return;
    if ($message->text != '/start') return;

    return $bot->sendMessage([
        'chat_id' => $update->chat()->id,
        'text' => 'Добро пожаловать!\nВведите свой пин-код c помощью команды /pincode\n\nПример: /pincode 1234',
        'reply_markup' => [
            'inline_keyboard' => [[
                ['text' => 'link', 'url' => 'https://core.telegram.org'],
                ['text' => 'Test', 'callback_data' => 'test123']
            ]]
        ]
    ]);
});

// Callback
$bot->addHandler(function (Update $update) use ($bot) {
    if (!$query = $update->callback_query ?? false) return;
    if ($query->data != 'test123') return;

    return $bot->answerCallbackQuery([
        'callback_query_id' => $query->id,
        'text' => 'Success!',
        'show_alert' => true
    ]);
});




// Handling bot updates
echo 'Bot is working...'.PHP_EOL;

$last_offset = 0;
while (true) {
    $updates = $bot->getUpdates([
        'offset' => $last_offset + 1
    ]);
    foreach ($updates as $update) {
        echo "Update recieved: $update->update_id" . PHP_EOL;
        $bot->handleUpdate($update);
        $last_offset = $update->update_id;
    }
}
```

Запустить бота с помощью команды:

```bsh
php index.php
```